# Error creating array of class

Tags: c++

I have a class of the following form:

```
class T
{
   public:
   /// Constructor
   T(const std::string& baseName);
};
```

Now within the main() method I am trying to create an array of the objects of the class using:

```
  T* s = new T[20](baseFileName);
```

I am not getting where I am making a mistake...can someone please help.

The error which I am getting is:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: the error you're receiving would be hard-pressed to be clearer. The language doesn't support array initialization in the fashion you're using. If you're looking for alternatives, try `std::vector<T> s(20, T(baseFileName));` (which frankly, you should be using anyway rather than allowing raw pointers to own dynamic resources).

Comment: Look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/arrays-call-default-ctor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create the array of objects like below:

```
T* s = new T[20]; //allocating 20 objects
```

now you can call your desired function by making a little change:

```
class T
{
   public:
   T(){};//default constructor
   /// Constructor
   SetValue(const std::string& baseName);
};
```

call the function using a loop:

```
for( int i=0 ; i<20;i++)
s[i].SetValue(baseString);
```

Comment: This won't work, the type does not have a default constructor.

Comment: please see my code carefully, I have suggested to add a default constructor :)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. You can't do this:

```
T* s = new T[20](baseFileName);
```

More specifically, you can't have that `(baseFileName)` bit when you use new. Just add a default constructor to T and fill it in yourself. Maybe add a method to your T class that returns array for you without you having to loop every time you need to construct one.

```
T * s = new T[20];
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { s[i].setName(baseFileName); }
```

Or since you already know what the array is going to look like at compile-time:

```
T s [20] {baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName,baseFileName, baseFileName};
```

Comment: Note that the last example will probably not do what OP needs.